# I see an `onprogress` when I inspect a `Form` element. Can I use it?

Tags: html, dom, upload, dom-events, form-submit

I see an `onprogress` when I inspect a `Form` element, on Chrome and Firefox (both latest stable versions). Can I use it to monitor the progress of the form submission?

I want to submit/upload a file (that will be big most of the time) to a server that is not under my control, I can't just do a `POST` to it with `XMLHttpRequest` because it won't send any of the CORS required headers. So I'm going for the form/iframe way, creating a `form` element with all the fields, add a file input, append to the file input the file instance I got from another dialog, create an iframe and set the target of the form to the name of the iframe.

Is this `onprogress` attribute something I can use? I can't find any docs regarding the `onprogress` attribute *of* a form. Is that just an inherited attribute or does it actually work?